# Disable autoscrolling when inserting in List View (win32 API, C)

Tags: c, winapi, listview, win32gui

I'm inserting an item in my common control listview like this:

```
void InsertRow (HWND hWnd, char *col1, char *col2)
{
    LV_ITEM     lvItem;

    lvItem.mask = 0;
    lvItem.iItem = 0;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.iItem = ListView_InsertItem (hWnd, &lvItem);

    lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.pszText = col1;
    lvItem.cchTextMax = strlen (lvItem.pszText);
    ListView_SetItem (hWnd, &lvItem);

    lvItem.iSubItem = 1;
    lvItem.pszText = col2;
    lvItem.cchTextMax = strlen (lvItem.pszText);
    ListView_SetItem (hWnd, &lvItem);
}
```

and works fine, but it is a pain because the vertical scroll goes back to the top of the list, so if I'm watching an item and call this insert function I lost my view, and have to scroll back manually, making my program impossible to work with.

How ca I prevent this autoscrolling?

I'm programming in C, with the win32 API directly (not MFC).

P.D.: ListView style:
`LVS_SINGLESEL | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|LVS_REPORT`

Comment: From my experience of working with native list boxes etc, I find their default behavior quite crude. What you could attempt is to "subclass" the listbox, ie run a custom windproc for some messages. In this case you should probably look for WM_VSCROLL or similar. Whenever you are adding an item to the list, set a flag "no_scroll" in your program. If the subclassed windproc gets a scroll message while "no_scroll" is set, discard it.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to get the current top position, insert the new item, and then (programatically) scroll back to the saved top position.

Comment: Or `ListView_EnsureVisible` which will do the grunt work for you

Comment: For some reason, it doesnt works. I call first topItem = ListView_GetTopIndex(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LISTA)) and get the first visible item, then insert the item and last I call ListView_EnsureVisible(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LISTA), topItem, TRUE), but that doesn't works. However EnsureVisible return TRUE.

Comment: This is similar to the method I used, but I had to actually set the selected item. It made scrolling a pain int he arse, but it was the best way I could find to do it.

Comment: @JoseLuis: What happened?  The way you're using it, `ListView_EnsureVisible` will only ensure that the old top item becomes visible.  It won't necessarily restore the old scroll position.

Comment: @jamesdlin: After making the old top item visible, you can use `ListView_GetItemRect()` and `ListView_GetTopIndex()` to easily calcalate if the item is at the top of the control or not, and if not then scroll the ListView that many pixels to place the item at the top again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call ListView_GetItem to get the index of the item you want to watch
2. Call ListView_EnsureVisible(hWnd, index_you_want_to_watch, TRUE) every time you insert a new row.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch the ListView to virtual mode (apply the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style and then use the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification to supply your data to the ListView when requested), then you can use `ListView_SetItemCountEx()` to add/insert/remove items.  It has a `LVSICF_NOSCROLL` flag to prevent scrolling.